# hi I'm learning scala and trying to split an array of strings but I am getting a mismatch error could someone please help me?

Tags: scala, loops, type-mismatch

```
def strlist(list: List[String]): String = {
    for (elem <- list){
         println(elem)}
}
```

error gives me this:

```
Error:(320, 17) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
      for (elem <- list){println(elem)}
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear, isn't it? You said that the method should return a single `String` and yet your implementation is just a `foreach` that prints each element of the `List`, that results in `Unit` not in `String`; not sure what was your idea? Why returning a single `String`? - Anyways, since you are new to the language you would be better to ask those questions in a chat format like [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) or [**discord**](https://discord.gg/8ERXAyaR) rather than in **SO**.

Comment: the code you posted doesn't split anything, it simply prints the elements in the list.  the way you've written it, isn't very functional (or idiomatic scala).  a more functional approach would be to map the `println` function over the list... 

```list.foreach(println)``` which expands to ```list.foreach(elem -> println(elem))```  (also note that `foreach` doesn't return a value but `map` does.)

Comment: Actually re-reading your question and I'm confused.  What does it mean to split an array of string?  typically one splits a string into an array, or joins a string-array into a single string.  so, basically, it looks like you've already done the split... it's your array of strings.  can you try explaining what you are trying to accomplish a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your function definition, you are returning a `String`, however in the implementation you are not returning anything. Hence the error says, you are returning a `Unit` but required is `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification to your code. And hope you get some additional info from above comments & answers. Cheers !

```
def strlist(list: List[String]): Unit= {
   for (elem <- list){
        println(elem)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! But can I ask how do I do it if I also wanna return a string and not a Unit?

Comment: That depends. How should your output look like. Cause you have an input of strings and which string you wanna return from your function ?

Comment: I want to return a separate string for each element